# Using Visual Studio as a Task-Focused IDE

Tags: ide, visual-studio

Are there patterns or libraries or any official Microsoft SDK for using Visual Studio as a specifically Task-Focused UI?

For example, both [Revolution R (IDE for the R language)](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com) and SQL 2012 (and I think SQL 2008 and possibly 2005) use Visual Studio as the underlying IDE framework.

Is there an officially supported SDK and/or examples/samples for doing this type of thing?

I am building a language Parser for an existing language - whose only available IDE is INSANELY expensive - using Irony (and eventually will generate a Language Service as well).

Any direct or indirect suggestions/answers are appreciated.

Comment: i would say if the only IDE for a language is insanely expensive there is a reason for that.

Comment: You'd be wrong @Ryathal...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Visual Studio Shell.  The [Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Isolated)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx) provides a foundation on which you can build your own custom-branded tools environment.

Visual Studio Shell is part of the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668).  A [redistributable runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30670) is provided.

See also http://studioshell.codeplex.com/